# Firebase Crashlytics for iOS - Why does it need a build phase?

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics, robovm

The official instructions require adding a build phase ""${PROJECT_DIR}/Fabric.framework/run" to get Firebase Crashlytics working for iOS. What is the purpose of this build phase?

We are not having a traditional XCode project but rather a RoboVM app, and we are not sure if it is possible to replicate this build phase in the RoboVM app setting.

Comment: Here it will uniquely identifies your account on Fabric with the unique provided, so that while running it will add entries/ logs in your account only

Comment: I guess, why does it have to do it with a build phase rather than just initialization code in the app? That seems to complicate things for non XCode project.

Comment: I don't think you can integrate crashanalytics other than XCode. You can ask for support though.